# Sharing an Image with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework, share, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to share an image with whatever app is selected by the user on mobile (using Ionic).

This is my html:

```
<img ng-src="{{myurl}}"  alt=""/>
```

This is my controller:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, myImg);
```

How do I pass the image itself to the controller so that myImg can be shared?

Answer (score 0):

`window.plugins.socialsharing.share` is your ionic/cordova specific code, not your angular controller.

If you are using controller as syntax, you need
`controller.myImg = imgUrl;`

Then in the html you need
`<img ng-src="{{controller.myImg}}" />`

Or if you can inject and bind to the scope
`$scope.myImg = imgUrl` and `<img ng-src="{{myImg}}" />`

Comment: Thank you! it helped. I mistakenly thought the parameter for the social sharing window was the image itself. Now I understand it is the image url. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are on the same Controller of the view with the `img` tag, and you are correctly viewing the image, your share method could be:

```
$scope.share = function(){
  window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
    'My message here', // message
    null, // subject
    $scope.myurl // image or a path 'www/img/my-image.png'
  );
};
```